# adminMongo for Mac :A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I download adminMongo from https://github.com/mrvautin/adminMongo/releases/download/1.0.0/adminMongo_Mac.zip。

When i open it alert fllow error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/private/var/folders/zb/l60pvq_12f77tfngqzc39xl40000gn/T/AppTranslocation/D2863A66-8764-4611-A478-5EAC27BF279E/d/adminMongo.app/Contents/Resources/app/data/dbStats.db'
at Error (native
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permissions problem creating the monitoring database. You can either check your permissions to ensure the process can write to the folder to create the embedded database or turn monitoring off.

Turning monitoring off is done by setting `monitoring` to `false`:

`{
    "app": {
        "monitoring": false
    }
}`